# Download multiple uploaded files in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form input which can upload multiple files. So all the files paths are saved in the database as an array of strings . Below is my controller to download the files. I wanted to know how I can go about presenting each file to be downloaded in blade view. So I could download a single file at a time. My controller below. It works only when downloading a single file. I get this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

```
public function download($id) {
        $deal = Deal::findorFail($id);
        $files = $deal->uploads;
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            return Storage::download($file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you have in the $files ?

Comment: From what I see, you're trying to iterate over the `uploads` property (column) of your findOrFailed `Deal`. I guess `uploads` contain a string. Do you store one file or many file with string separators for example?

Comment: @Mtxz I store many files with string separators in uploads column

Answer (score 2):

```
public function download($id) {
    $deal = Deal::findorFail($id);
    $files = $deal->uploads;

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        return Storage::download($file);
--------^^^^^^-------------------------
    }
}
```

when you return first file, it breaks foreach loop. So you have to return all files together. And only way to achieve this, is creating a zip file that contains all files..

For this purpose you may use [chumper/zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper) package

```
$zipper = Zipper::make(public_path('/documents/deals.zip'));
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zipper->add(public_path($file)); // update it by your path
}
$zipper->close();
return response()
    ->download(
        public_path('/temporary_files/' . "deals.zip"),
        "deals.zip", 
        ["Content-Type" => "application/zip"]
    );
```

**update**

Add accessor to Deal model to get files as array

Deal Model

```
php artisan getUploadsAttribute($attribute){
   return explode(",",$attributes);
}
```

Comment: thanks but when I try to download it gives me this error `The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\accounts\public\temporary_files/deals.zip" does not exist`

Comment: @lawkunchi did you install the package ?

Comment: Yeah I did install the package

Comment: @lawkunchi Oh I thought there were some accessor at background and never ask. But weird, it should throw error like $files are not iterablere or something.. whatever. Can you add your deal model an accessor for uploads file and then try again ? I'll show you how to do

Comment: Yes I think files are not iterable since I stored them as a string using `implode(',', $paths);` Where `$paths` is the array of the uploaded files